# MYSQL connect and query 2 dbs on 2 different server

Tags: php, mysql

MYSQL connect and query 2 dbs on 2 different server

THANKS in advance for any help,

I've been trying for a week to get this to work,
and have googled various examples on this site and on others.
i'm trying to connect 2 db, on the same server.

i can get data from each seperatly, but i don't know how to wrire code to combine / join the data

this is my incorrect code based on numerous help and 
how to post i've read online. ANY help or clues are welcome.
If i can just get anything to output / print i would be happy

```
// connect to db1 contact info
$host1='db1hostname';
$user1='db1user';
$password1='db1pw';
$database1='db1user';

// connect to db2, phone call info
$host2='db2hostname';
$user2='db2user';
$password2='db2pw';
$database2='db2user';

$connect1 = mysql_connect($host1, $user1, $password1) OR DIE 
('Unable to connect to database! Please try again later.');

$connect2 = mysql_connect($host2, $user2, $password2) OR DIE 
('Unable to connect to database! Please try again later.');

// i think this is where things start to go wrong

mysql_select_db($database1, $connect1);
mysql_select_db($database2, $connect2);

    // i want to join these 2 tables from diff db by the caller info
```

which is a cell number
        // the database 2 info comes from a phone call records table
 and can't be altered,  so i can't connect the 2 tbls by the table primary id
 because i never know what the id will be for each call in db2,
 i wish to connect the 2 db tables by caller cell number

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT `m`.`id`, `m`.`created`, `m`.`caller`, `m`.`content_text`, 
`c`.`iname`, `c`.`caller`  
FROM database1.contacts c, database2.messages m    
WHERE `c`.`caller` = `m`.`caller` ") or die(mysql_error()); 

// i then want to print the results to a table

while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data ))
```

Comment: Do you really need to be using `mysql_query`? It's super out of date and being removed from PHP, so if this is new code, you shouldn't be using it at all.

Comment: no its just what i've been using, have not built a site in a while so this is what i know

Comment: Your code makes it appear that they are on different servers? db1hostname, db2hostname

Comment: To keep up to date, a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) should help. The best practice is to use a [PHP framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) to take care of things like this, or barring that, an ORM like [Doctrine](http://doctrine-project.org/) or [Propel](http://propelorm.org/). If you want to do something low-level, [PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) is probably the best way using standard PHP.

Comment: i'm hosting on godaddy, i know i need to find another place and i'm working on that, when i go to each db it says the server is the same number, the only thing diff on each $host is the db name, everything that follows is the same

Comment: i spoke to godaddy and they said my db are on diff servers,

Answer (score 0):

Connect to your first database and when you want to run a query in the second database just use the simple way like in below code.

```
$query = "SELECT t1.*, t2.*
          FROM tableOfDB1 t1
          LEFT JOIN database2.tableOfDB2 t2 ON t1.ID = ts2.TableOne_ID
          ";
```

Or if you want data only from db2

```
 $query = "SELECT  t2.*
          FROM database2.tableOfDB2  t2";
```

In your example try this

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT `m`.`id` AS mID, `m`.`created` AS mCreated, `m`.`caller` AS mCaller, `m`.`content_text`, 
`c`.`iname` AS cIname, `c`.`caller` AS cCaller  
FROM database1.contacts c, database2.messages m    
WHERE `c`.`caller` = `m`.`caller` ") or die(mysql_error()); 

while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($data) )
{
  echo "<br>mCaller: ".$row['mCaller'];
 echo "<br>cCaller: ".$row['cCaller'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If, as you say, the databases are on the same server, then you can do everything with one connection. You have to be explicit about your database names in your queries, but then you can do everything else in a very straightforward way.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19039718/reference-column-in-seperate-database/19040228#19040228